# Breaking this c++ code into separate class specification file and function definition files?

Tags: c++

The assignment asks me to write a class named car, create a car object, have it accelerate and brake 5x by 5mph each. This is completed, but I want to separate the functions and class definitions from the main.cpp... and I guess I just don't have a full understanding how to do this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Car class declaration.

class Car 
{
    private:
    // member variables
    int yearModel;
    string make;
    int speed;

    public:
    Car(int carYearModel, string carMake, int carSpeed)
    { yearModel = carYearModel;
      make = carMake;
      speed = carSpeed; }

    void accelerate(int mph)
    { speed += mph; }
    void brake(int mph)
    { speed -= mph; }

    int getSpeed () const
    { return speed; }
};

int main()
    {
    int count;
    Car honda(2005, "Accord", 0);

    cout << "The starting speed is "  
     << honda.getSpeed() << endl << endl;

    cout << "We will now accelerate by 5 mph, 5 times.\n";
    system ("pause");

    for ( count = 0; count < 5; count++)
    {
        honda.accelerate(5);
        cout << "Speed is now: " << honda.getSpeed() 
             << " mph." << endl;
    }

    system ("pause");

    cout << endl << "Now we will brake by 5 mph, 5 times. \n";
    system ("pause");

    for ( count = 0; count < 5; count++)
    {
        honda.brake(5);
        cout << "Speed is now: " << honda.getSpeed() 
             << " mph." << endl;
    }

    system ("pause");

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Basically, your class should have just the function prototypes, and outside the class, define functions with qualified names, e.g. `Car::accelerate`.

Comment: Put `class Car` in file, say, `car.hpp` and use `#include "car.hpp"` in the original source file. (You will need to include `<string>` in `car.hpp`). You can put functions definitions in source file, say, `car.cpp` using @Mechanicalsnail advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Split declarations from definitions.
- move definitions to cpp files
- move declarations to hpp files

Most importantly

- ***never use `using namespace` in header files***

Car.hpp:

```
#ifndef CAR_INCLUDED_H
#define CAR_INCLUDED_H
#include <string>

class Car 
{
    private:
        int yearModel;
        std::string make;
        int speed;

    public:
        Car(int carYearModel, std::string carMake, int carSpeed);
        void accelerate(int mph);
        void brake(int mph);
        int getSpeed () const;
};

#endif
```

Car.cpp:

```
#include "Car.hpp"

Car::Car(int carYearModel, std::string carMake, int carSpeed)
{
    yearModel = carYearModel;
    make = carMake;
    speed = carSpeed;
}

void Car::accelerate(int mph)
{
    speed += mph;
}
void Car::brake(int mph)
{
    speed -= mph;
}

int Car::getSpeed() const
{
    return speed;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "Car.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int count;
    Car honda(2005, "Accord", 0);

    cout << "The starting speed is "  
        << honda.getSpeed() << endl << endl;

    cout << "We will now accelerate by 5 mph, 5 times.\n";
    system ("pause");

    for ( count = 0; count < 5; count++)
    {
        honda.accelerate(5);
        cout << "Speed is now: " << honda.getSpeed() 
            << " mph." << endl;
    }

    system ("pause");

    cout << endl << "Now we will brake by 5 mph, 5 times. \n";
    system ("pause");

    for ( count = 0; count < 5; count++)
    {
        honda.brake(5);
        cout << "Speed is now: " << honda.getSpeed() 
            << " mph." << endl;
    }

    system ("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: May I suggest initializer list in constructor?

Comment: @PetrBudnik you may. Although it has _literally_ nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Thanks all for the help. And I'll look up initialization lists before I turn it in